# Returning MULTIPLE Lists using JSON and Serializer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, webmethod

I'm sending a List from my ASP.NET WebMethod to my Javascript using this:

```
List<Person> plist = new List<Person>();

string json = "";
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
json = oSerializer.Serialize(plist );

return json;
```

And I'm using this to retrieve these values from my JS:

```
function onSuccess(val) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(val)
        obj.forEach(function (entry) {
               console.log(entry);
       });
}
```

Everything works well. However now I want to return MULTIPLE lists such as:

```
List<Person> plist = new List<Person>();
List<Car> carlist = new List<Car>();
List<Car> jeeplist = new List<Car>();
```

using the same mechanism I used before. How can I insert two lists to the Serializer and print them from my JS?

**EDIT**

How do I get the values from the JS? Is this the way?

```
obj.forEach(function (entry) {
         entry.forEach(function (act)
         {
               console.log(act);
         })
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct TwoLists
{
    public List<Person> plist;
    public List<Car> carlist;
}
```

...

```
TwoLists lists;
lists.plist = new List<Person>();
lists.carlist = new List<Car>();
...
string json = "";
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
json = oSerializer.Serialize(lists);

return json;
```

...

```
function onSuccess(val) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(val);
    obj.plist.forEach(function (entry) {
        console.log(entry);
    });
    obj.carlist.forEach(function (entry) {
        console.log(entry);
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to pass more than 2 lists, is it possible?

Comment: You can pass as many lists, or other data structures as you wish.